# Universal Analytics code tracked for one day and then it stopped. Why?

Tags: google-analytics

I added Google Analytics on website [Bons Alunos](http://www.bonsalunos.pt) and I got data on 27 of December.

Since then I didn't receive any data even if I visited the site from different devices (mobile, desktop, etc).

I checked on Google Analytics Admin section and it says the code is not installed ... But it is ...

On the head section of my homepage I can see the tracking code ...

And why did it work for one day and then it stopped?

Any idea what might be wrong?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your source code, it looks like you're missing an opening bracket before the first function statement:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-46470961-2', 'bonsalunos.pt');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```